# inserting into a database only the filled inputs in a html table

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a Laravel 5 application where i am using jQuery DataTables plugin. at the datatable I have 3 input fields in each row. what I want to do is to insert all the row inputs that are filled. In each row you have to fill all 3 inputs so that the data would be posted in database. (The database is sql server.) I have tried something but it's not working. Here is what I've tried in the controller store method:

```
$dates = $request->get('month');
    $values = $request->get('value');
    $comments = $request->get('comment');
    $reports = []; // this will keep what we input in our DB
    /*if(!empty($row['month']) && !empty($row['value']) && !empty($row['comment'])){
        foreach($row as $rows){
            $index = +1;
        }
    }*/
    if(!empty($dates) && !empty($values)){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++)
    {
        //here i am dividing month and year
        $date = explode('-', $dates[$i]);
        $year = $date[0];
        $month = $date[1]; // <-- line 75

            $reports[] = Reports::create([
                'month' => $month,
                'year' => $year,
                'value' => $values[$i],
                'comment' => $comments[$i]
            ]);

        }
    }
    return $reports;
```

This throws me an error though:

```
ErrorException in ReportController.php line 75:
Undefined offset: 1
```

I've searched about it and it says that i'm passing an array instead of a string.

here is the stacktrace (part of it):

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1', 'E:\socgen\soc-gen\app\Http\Controllers\ReportController.php', '75', array('request' => object(Request), 'dates' => array('2015-06', '2015-02', ''), 'values' => array('369', '22223', ''), 'comments' => array('878', '5466', ''), 'reports' => array(object(Reports)), 'i' => '1', 'date' => array(''), 'year' => '', 'month' => '06')) in ReportController.php line 75
```

Any help or hint is appreciated

Comment: What is your code in line 75

Comment: what's `$row`? where it is coming from?

Comment: @itachi sorry that was a test that i did earlier. it should've been commented in here

Comment: why you are going through all this hassle just to store dates, months, years in different columns? `yyy-mm-dd` date format is fine.

Comment: i just need the month and the year and at the end i need to perform a query scope to filter only the data during a year.

Answer (score 0):

The official doc on php.net reads the following about explode function.

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of **string** formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the **string** delimiter.

which concludes that explode function of php takes only strings as argument and in your case you are passing an array. I would suggest you to first put your data in array into a string and then pass it to explode. e.g

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++)
{
    //remove empty indexes from your array 
    array_diff( $dates[$i], array( '' ) );

    //create a new string and put your date into it.
    $dateString = $dates[$i];

    $date = explode('-', $dateString);
    $year = $date[0];
    $month = $date[1]; // <-- line 75

    //rest of your code goes here 
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work. the problem is that when the values are posted, they come as an array. and i want to get only the values that are not blank. atm all i get is $dates('2015-06','2015-07','') if i leave the last row without a value.

Comment: use isset to check if the current index of your array is not blank. More over you may also use array_diff(); to filter out blank indexes from you array

Comment: okay so this worked. it removed the empty arrays. but still i'm getting the same errors when i leave an empty row on the table

Comment: change your columns into nullable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79884/discussion-between-xhulio-and-khan-shahrukh).